# Sometimes I get 0 padding for accordian content sometimes with padding

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am wondering why my jQuery UI accordion content intermittently displays with & without padding. I have styled the accordian with padding

```
#sidebar .ui-widget-content {
  border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px 10px 15px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

[This video on Screenr (22secs)](http://screenr.com/sMv) shows whats happening. 1st screen shows search content without padding after 1 refresh, it has padding. Sometimes I get no padding on the meta list but padding on the search content. What might be happening. In firebug, I see that padding 0'ed out on `element.style` is the cause. So it appears jQuery UI sets the padding? But why does it change randomly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first suspicion is that the plugin is applying either .css() calls or adding other classes to the accordion upon instantiation or upon sliding content.

I have played with re-styling the accordion and by far the hardest UI component to alter... purley because of it's onchange calls within the plugin...

I actually dont have a solution now, but i hope that's a hint in the right direction